# how to convert k.variable, addweights to pytorch code

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

i have a code written by tensorflow code i need to convert to pytorch.

i think i almost done with this but i'm not sure about detail.

first i have

```
class adaptive_implicit_trans(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(adaptive_implicit_trans, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        conv_shape = (1,1,64,64)
        self.it_weights = self.add_weight(
            shape = (1,1,64,1),
            initializer = initializers.get('ones'),
            constraint = constraints.NonNeg(),
            name = 'ait_conv')
        kernel = np.zeros(conv_shape)
        r1 = sqrt(1.0/8)
        r2 = sqrt(2.0/8)
        for i in range(8):
            _u = 2*i+1
            for j in range(8):
                _v = 2*j+1
                index = i*8+j
                for u in range(8):
                    for v in range(8):
                        index2 = u*8+v
                        t = cos(_u*u*pi/16)*cos(_v*v*pi/16)
                        t = t*r1 if u==0 else t*r2
                        t = t*r1 if v==0 else t*r2
                        kernel[0,0,index2,index] = t
        self.kernel = k.variable(value = kernel, dtype = 'float32')

    def call(self, inputs):
        self.kernel = self.kernel*self.it_weights
        y = k.conv2d(inputs,
                        self.kernel,
                        padding = 'same',
                        data_format='channels_last')
        return y

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

and i need to convert it to pytorch code.

so i made this.

```
class It_Weight(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ReLU = nn.ReLU()
        self.it_weights = nn.Parameter(torch.autograd.Variable(torch.ones((1, 64, 1, 1)),
                                                               requires_grad=True))

    def forward(self, input):
        y = input.to('cuda') * self.it_weights
        return self.ReLU(y)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape


class Kernel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        conv_shape = (64, 64, 1, 1)
        kernel = torch.zeros(conv_shape).cuda()
        r1 = sqrt(1.0 / 8)
        r2 = sqrt(2.0 / 8)
        for i in range(8):
            _u = 2 * i + 1
            for j in range(8):
                _v = 2 * j + 1
                index = i * 8 + j
                for u in range(8):
                    for v in range(8):
                        index2 = u * 8 + v
                        t = cos(_u * u * pi / 16) * cos(_v * v * pi / 16)
                        t = t * r1 if u == 0 else t * r2
                        t = t * r1 if v == 0 else t * r2
                        kernel[index, index2, 0, 0] = t
        self.kernel = torch.autograd.Variable(kernel)

    def forward(self):
        return self.kernel

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

class adaptive_implicit_trans(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.it_weights = It_Weight()
        self.kernel = Kernel()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.kernel1 = self.it_weights(self.kernel())     # 출력도 kernel사이즈랑 동일
        y = F.conv2d(inputs, self.kernel1)
        return y

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

the number of class was increased but it was my best in order to avoid error.

i don't know where is wrong.

i have been trying to train this pytorch code. but performance is lower than tensorflow code.

where should i edit ??

please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.